# Pandas: Conversão de Dataframes para imagem

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Dado um Dataframe como o seguinte:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp' : [13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000114, 1],
               'name_emp': ['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin', 'Souza'],
               'name_dep': ['Ronaldo','Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Bruno'],
               'weight_1': [8,9,10,11,12],
               'weight_2':[5,6,7,8,9] })
```

Há alguma função para converter o Dataframe em algum arquivo .png, .jpg., .pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para a conversão do dataframe em imagem você deve utilizar o `matplotlib`, nele existe uma função chamada `imshow` do módulo `matplotlib.pyplot` onde é passado a feature(x_i) do dataframe que você deseja montar a imagem e o `matplotlib.pyplot` a exibe.

Caso você queira salvar pode fazer uso da `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig('imagem.png')`.
Abaixo segue um exemplo de utilização disponibilizado no seguinte [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tools.plotting import table

ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False) # no visible frame
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis

table(ax, df)  # where df is your data frame

plt.savefig('mytable.png')
```